# Oque tem de errado neste código de inserir dados no mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer um código para inserir dados na base de dados `localhost`, porém não estou conseguindo inserir, e não sei o porquê.

Minhas configurações de banco de dados estão corretas e as tabelas também. O erro com certeza é no código, então gostaria de descobrir qual o problema:

```
<?php
include("admin/configs/config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="form">
            <input type="text" name="r_nome" placeholder="Nome">
            <br><br>
            <input type="text" name="r_usuario" placeholder="Usuário">
            <br><br>
            <input type="password" name="r_senha" placeholder="Senha">
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar">
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $nome = $_POST["r_nome"];
        $usuario = $_POST["r_usuario"];
        $senha = $_POST["r_senha"];
        $foto = "uploads/";

        if (empty($usuario) || empty($nome) || empty($senha)) {
            echo "Preencha todos os campos!";
    }else{

     $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, usuario, senha, foto) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', '$foto')";

  }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Você não está executando a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro a leitura da documentação do PHP sobre a classe `Mysqli` e/ou `PDO`

> [**Mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)
>
> [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php)

Mas basicamente você precisa iniciar a conexão com o banco de dados, estou falando no caso de não existir, mas para vc entender a sequência:

```
#dados de acesso ao servidor com o banco de dados
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$bancodedados = "seu_banco_de_dados";

#inicia a classe Mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $bancodedados);    

#verifica a coneção
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Falha na conexão: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

#sua query
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, usuario, senha, foto) VALUES ('$nome', '$usuario', '$senha', '$foto')";

#execução da query    
if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Dados salvos no banco.";
} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}

#fecha a conexão
$mysqli->close();
```

Sugestão: Para a `action` na mesma página, você pode nem declarar esse atributo:

```
<form method="POST" name="form">
```

Answer (score 0):

Em

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
```

preencha o valor de `action` com o nome do seu programa PHP; caso seu programa se chame *programa.php*, faça

```
<form action="programa.php" method="POST" name="form">
```

No código PHP, falta declarar o driver de acesso ao banco de dados. Caso ainda não tenha instalado o servidor de banco, recomendo os seguintes links,

- http://www.contagia.com.br/blog/instalando-configurando-wampserver/
- https://jorgeabrantes.com.br/blog/wampserver/wamp-server-como-configurar-o-wamp-server-para-funcionar-em-rede-local/
- https://king.host/wiki/artigo/como-conectar-um-banco-de-dados-mysql-utilizando-php/

Comment: No meu código, não estou usando o "action" pois o código já está no mesmo arquivo.